# How i can use the value of item of ngFor out from same element?

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is my element

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items |xxxx ; let l = count "> <div>

<!--use {{l}} in other element-->
```

How can I get the value of `{{ l }}` to use it outside this div or to use it in *component.ts* after filter directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your template in `<ng-container>`. Like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items |xxxx ; let l = count ">
    <div ><div>
    <!--use {{l}} in other element-->
</ng-container>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue

Comment: thanks for your answer.
but in that's way everything inside ng-container it's will looping
i want use it on other section without loop

Comment: You cannot use variable `l` outside its scope! Declare a class variable and use thst instead.